# Pushing back tokens in Happy and Alex

Tags: haskell, ghc, happy

I'm parsing a language which has both `<` and `<<`. In my Alex definition I've got something that contains something like

```
tokens :-

"<"             { token Lt }
"<<"            { token (BinOp Shl) }
```

so whenever I encounter `<<`, that gets tokenized as a left shift and *not* as to less-than's. This is generally a good thing, since I end up throwing out whitespace after tokenization and want to differentiate between `1 < < 2` and `1 << 2`. However, there are other times I wish `<<` had been read as two `<`. For example, I have things like

```
<<A>::B>
```

which I want read like

```
< < A > :: B >
```

Obviously I can try to adjust my Happy parser rules to accommodate for the extra cases, but that scales badly. In other imperative parser generators, I might try to do something like push back "part" of the token (something like `push_back("<")` when I encountered `<<` but I only needed `<`).

Has anyone else had such a problem and, if so, how did you deal with it? Are there ways of "pushing back" tokens in Happy? Should I instead try to keep a whitespace token around (I'm actually leaning towards the last alternative - although being a huge headache, it would let me deal with `<<` by just making sure there is no whitespace between the two `<`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While I initially went with @Jon's answer, I ended up running into a variety of precedence related issues (think precedence around `expr < expr` vs `expr << expr`) which caused me a lot of headaches. I recently (successfully) back to lexing `<<` as one token. The solution was twofold:

1. I bit the bullet and added extra rules for `<<` (where previously I only had rules for `<`). For the example in the question (`<<A>::B>`) my rule went from something like

   ```
   ty_qual_path
     : '<' ty_sum '>' '::' ident
   ```

   to

   ```
   ty_qual_path
     : '<' ty_sum '>' '::' ident
     | '<<' ty_sum '>' '::' ident '>' '::' ident
   ```

   (The actual rule was actually a bit more involved, but that is not for this answer).
2. I found a clever way to deal with token that started with `>` (these would cause problems around things like `vector<i32,vector<i32>>` where the last `>>` was a token): use a [threaded lexer (section 2.5.2)](https://www.haskell.org/happy/doc/html/sec-monads.html), exploit the `{%% ... }` RHS of rules which lets you reconsider the lookahead token, and add a `pushToken` facility to my parser monad ([this turned out to be quite simple - here is exactly what I did](https://github.com/harpocrates/language-rust/blob/fdea2c6713db297f5bc17a65de35724725abd461/src/Language/Rust/Parser/ParseMonad.hs)). I then added a dummy rule - something like

   ```
   gt :: { () }
     : {- empty -}   {%% \tok ->
         case tok of
           Tok ">>"  -> pushToken (Tok ">")  *> pushToken (Tok ">")
           Tok ">="  -> pushToken (Tok "=")  *> pushToken (Tok ">")
           Tok ">>=" -> pushToken (Tok ">=") *> pushToken (Tok ">")
           _         -> pushToken tok
       }
   ```

   And every time in some other rule I expected a `>` but there could also be any other token starting with `>`, I would precede the `>` token with `gt`. This has the effect of looking ahead to the next token which may could start with `>` without being `>`, and try to convert that token into one `>` token and another token for the "rest" of the initial token.

Answer (score 2):

I don’t know how to express this in Happy, but you don’t need a separate “whitespace” token. You can parse `<` or `>` as a distinct “angle bracket” token when immediately followed by an operator symbol in the input, with no intervening whitespace.

Then, when you want to parse an operator, you join a sequence of angles and operators into a single token. When you want to treat them as brackets, you just deal with them separately as usual.

So `a << b` would be tokenised as:

```
identifier "a"
left angle      -- joined with following operator
operator "<"
identifier "b"
```

When parsing an operator, you concatenate angle tokens with the following operator token, producing a single `operator "<<"` token.

`<<A>::B>` would be tokenised as:

```
left angle
operator "<"    -- accepted as bracket
identifier "A"
right angle
operator "::"
identifier "B"
operator ">"    -- accepted as bracket
```

When parsing angle-bracketed terms, you accept both angle tokens and `<`/`>` operators.

This relies on your grammar not being ambiguous wrt. whether you should parse an operator name or a bracketed thing.

Comment: Smart idea! Although I haven't yet managed to find a way to get two tokens by Alex, I can see how this will work. Thanks!

Comment: @Alec: Yeah, I’ve only ever used this technique in Parsec, where you have lookahead (e.g. `try (Operator <$> char '<' <* notFollowedBy symbol) <|> LeftAngle <$> char '<'`), but that doesn’t look possible to express directly in Alex. You could probably encode it without lookahead somehow.